# Selection sort in Card Hand

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to implement selection sort into a hand of cards when cards are added. This is my current code. I understand how selection sort is supposed to work and was just looking for advice on how to start to implement it into my add function.

## Hand class

class newHand(object):

```
def __init__(self, label = ""):
    """
    create an empty collection of cards with the given label
    """
    self.label = label
    self.cards = []


def add(self, card):
    """
    # Implements selection sort
    pre: card is a Card
    post: appended the card to the hand and sorts the deck
    """

    self.cards.append(card)


def sort(self):
    """
    post: arrange the cards in decending order
    """
    cards0 = self.cards
    cards1 = []
    while len(cards0) > 0:
        card = max(cards0)
        cards0.remove(card)
        cards1.append(card)
    self.cards = cards1


def dump(self):
    """
    post: outputs the contents in the hand
    """

    print(self.label + "'s Cards: ")
    for card in self.cards:
        print("\t", card)
```

Comment: Advice: don't implement your own sorting algorithm when `list.sort()` is already a function, and `sorted()` is also already a function. They're more efficient than anything you're going to make on your own.

Comment: I would do that if I could, i'm working through an assignment and we are supposed to use the code I provided and add the selection sort into add. I agree with you though, list.sort() is a much more efficient route.